# Can not switch off automatic brackets appearance in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I am a beginner programmer in Python with Pycharm. Currently I am typing in the editor and find it is inconvenient for me to use autotyping the closing bracket. Pycherm does it for me)) I meet the amount of settings in Pycharm - file - settings - editor - general as I did to switch off arising icons. I could not find the section with brackets. Is there any solution to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Settings (File --> Settings) go to:

> [Editor --> General --> Smart Keys](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-smart-keys.html)

Then there should be a setting called

```
Insert paired brackets (), [], {}, <>
```

Switch that off and that should stop the auto-completion of brackets

See the following link for more information on Smart Keys in PyCharm
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-smart-keys.html

The item 'Insert pair bracket' is a reference to the setting you were looking to set

Comment: Thanks! Insert paired brackets option - that is an option I looked for, that is great.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! If you're happy with my answer, if you could mark it as correct that would be great.

Comment: Yes, I forget about it being here the first time.